# How to log into Twitter with Splinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, authentication, splinter

I'm working with splinter and Python and I'm trying to setup some automation and log into Twitter.com

Having trouble though...

For example the password field's "name=session[password]" on Twitter.com/login

and the username is similar. I'm not exactly sure of the syntax or what this means, something with a cookie...
But I'm trying to fill in this field with splinters:

browser.fill('exampleName','exampleValue')

It isn't working... Just curious if there is a work around, or a way to fill in this form?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of doing this rather than using the official API?

Scripted logins to Twitter.com are against the Terms of Service, and Twitter employs multiple techniques to detect and disallow them. Accounts showing signs of automated login of this kind are liable to suspension or requests for security re-verification.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Although now I can see why they make it hard to do with Splinter. My purpose is to learn how to use splinter, and I run some twitter bots with the API or the wrapper tweepy. I was thinking it would be easier to use splinter over the api in some cases...